# Connecting into vsftpd in Docker

Tags: docker, ftp, vsftpd

I copied what is in this blog: https://www.xavignu.com/?p=1667 but can't ftp in.

I am running on Windows 10 using Docker Quickstart Terminal.
When I run

> docker --version

I get:

> Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4eee

I made some small changes. So my actual files are:
**vsftpd.conf**

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
pam_service_name=vsftpd.virtual
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/vftp/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
hide_ids=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

**vsftpd.virtual**

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user
account    required     pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
```

**vusers.txt**

```
ftpuser
letmein
```

**centos-vsftpd**

```
# Dockerfile for vsftpd on CentOS
FROM centos:7
#FROM fedora:14
MAINTAINER xavi@xavignu.com

RUN yum -y update; yum -y install which vsftpd net-tools vsftpd-sysvinit; yum clean all

COPY vusers.txt /etc/vsftpd/
RUN db_load -T -t hash -f /etc/vsftpd/vusers.txt /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user.db; rm -v /etc/vsftpd/vusers.txt; \ 
chmod 600 /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user.db
COPY vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd/
COPY vsftpd.virtual /etc/pam.d/
RUN mkdir -p /home/vftp/ftpuser; chown -R ftp:ftp /home/vftp

EXPOSE 20 21

CMD ["/usr/sbin/vsftpd","-obackground=NO"]
```

When I run:

> docker build -t centos-vsftpd -f centos-vsftpd .

I get

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB Step 1/10 : FROM
>   centos:7  ---> 5e35e350aded Step 2/10 : MAINTAINER xavi@xavignu.com 
>   ---> Using cache  ---> 5d3678c186ef Step 3/10 : RUN yum -y update; yum -y install which vsftpd net-tools vsftpd-sysvinit; yum clean all  ---> Using cache  ---> e8f9bd668fd7 Step 4/10 : COPY vusers.txt
>   /etc/vsftpd/  ---> Using cache  ---> e99de963d214 Step 5/10 : RUN
>   db_load -T -t hash -f /etc/vsftpd/vusers.txt
>   /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user.db; rm -v /etc/vsftpd/vusers.txt;
>   chmod 600 /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user.db  ---> Using cache  --->
>   2afd82b0d521 Step 6/10 : COPY vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd/  ---> Using
>   cache  ---> c2cf93124456 Step 7/10 : COPY vsftpd.virtual /etc/pam.d/ 
>   ---> Using cache  ---> 751b36e2a908 Step 8/10 : RUN mkdir -p /home/vftp/ftpuser; chown -R ftp:ftp /home/vftp  ---> Using cache 
>   ---> 8e40b2c6857f Step 9/10 : EXPOSE 20 21  ---> Using cache  ---> 721b161ef41f Step 10/10 : CMD ["/usr/sbin/vsftpd","-obackground=NO"] 
>   ---> Using cache  ---> d411b32e138a Successfully built d411b32e138a Successfully tagged centos-vsftpd:latest SECURITY WARNING: You are
>   building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker
>   host. All files and directories added to build context will have
>   '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset
>   permissions for sensitive files and directories.

When I run

> docker run -d --name myftp centos-vsftpd:latest; docker ps

I get:

> C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from
>   daemon: Conflict. The container name "/myftp" is already in use by
>   container
>   "05a1533975a6fb703a92d9a185f2ed5ffef6843f4ff5a3298037759cffadff85".
>   You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
>   name. See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
>   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
>   NAMES d069ad5b8751        fauria/vsftpd
>   "/usr/sbin/run-vsftp…"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours
>   0.0.0.0:20-21->20-21/tcp, 0.0.0.0:21100-21110->21100-21110/tcp   vsftpd bee37fe97faa        elwyn5150/get-started:part2       "python
>   app.py"          24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         80/tcp
>   getstartedlab_web.4.eyhn8lla4z9jk2w759yirkc40 cbd4e22a05f3
>   elwyn5150/get-started:part2       "python app.py"          24 hours
>   ago        Up 24 hours         80/tcp
>   getstartedlab_web.3.7jf7ko695b7vge176n4cvt5fu 1072a9d62add
>   elwyn5150/get-started:part2       "python app.py"          24 hours
>   ago        Up 24 hours         80/tcp
>   getstartedlab_web.5.714wm1hfrjt9kpwqgdomptbmh 6ca018732d0e
>   elwyn5150/get-started:part2       "python app.py"          24 hours
>   ago        Up 24 hours         80/tcp
>   getstartedlab_web.1.5w5v62j9zbhooeulx97v286q3 cfc72b5ba0fc
>   elwyn5150/get-started:part2       "python app.py"          24 hours
>   ago        Up 24 hours         80/tcp
>   getstartedlab_web.2.abdeplq9ocx0mgq890w034g85 f1921c8a441e
>   dockersamples/visualizer:stable   "npm start"              24 hours
>   ago        Up 24 hours         8080/tcp

When I try to ftp to localhost (using default port number), I get connection refused.

There are various things that I've tried but not worked for me. I've tried various IP addresses and numerous different port numbers but still been unable to connect.
I have also changed the Windows defender firewall 's inbound rules to allow other ports to work.

What host and port should I be using? 
What else can I try?